# How to have a toast appear on a if else statements on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, if-statement

I have been trying to get a toast to appear on my screen whenever a user types a certain name in the edit text box. When the user successfully types in the correct name I want the toast to display a successful message and if the name is not correct I want the toast to display an error message. Whenever I run the code below and type a name nothing appears whether right or wrong. This is what I have so far.

```
package com.example.app1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Invites extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText username;
    Button invite, finished;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invites);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        invite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.invite);
        finished = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finished);

        invite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (username.getText().toString().contains("Fname Lname")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Invites.this, "Invitation Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Invites.this, "User not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused from wehat you're asking vs what you've done in the code. Let's get some things straight. 

1. You want to test the case when the user clicks on the invite button? because this is what i'm understanding from your code. 
2. From your question i understand that you're trying to achieve this on a `onChange` event behaviour on the text field. 
3. Have you tried to put some debug points inside the `onClick` callback function to see if it goes there qwhen you press the button?

Comment: Hey @ALex to answer your questions. 1. Yes this is correct. 2. Yes this is also correct. 3. I had the debug log open while running the app and this is what appeared when clicking the button " D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10153; state: ENABLED "

Comment: By debug points i meant like actual breakpoints on the lines with the `Toast` calls and one on the line with the if.I just want to confirm that the callback is reached when you press the button so that we can exclude this from the problems list. So try this pls. Add breakpoints on those lines, start your app and press the button. Evaluate the `username.getText()` expression and see what is it's value. If this works ok, then there's something wrong with the toast library or the way you're using it.